# html5 validation figure tag structure

Tags: css, html

Please check Figure tag in html structure

html5 validation- Is  this structure allowed ?

```
<a href="#">
   <figure>
      <img src="" class="img-responsive" alt="">
      <figcaption>Family</figcaption>
  </figure>
</a>
```

and

```
<figure>
   <a href="#">
      <img src="" class="img-responsive" alt="">
      <figcaption>Family</figcaption>
   </a>
</figure>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first code snippet is correct, and passes validation if you add text to the alt attribute and a '#' in the src attribute.

http://validator.nu/